# How do I add custom error bars in Seaborn swarm plot

Tags: python, seaborn, errorbar, swarmplot

I am trying to make a column scatter plot, like the ones you could normally produce with Graphpad.

So far I have:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats
sns.set(style="white", rc={'figure.figsize':(11.7,8.27)})
plt.rcParams["axes.labelsize"] = 29


a=["X", "X", "X", "Y", "Y", "Y"]
b=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
c=["a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c"]
df = pd.DataFrame({"sample": a, "value": b,"rep": c})

ax = sns.stripplot(x="sample", y="value", data=df, palette="Set1", marker='v',s=18)
median_width = 0.2
for tick, text in zip(ax.get_xticks(), ax.get_xticklabels()):
    sample_name = text.get_text()  # "X" or "Y"

    median_val = df[df['sample']==sample_name].value.median()


    ax.plot([tick-median_width/2, tick+median_width/2], [median_val, median_val],
            lw=2, color='k')

yer1=(stats.sem(b[0:2]),stats.sem(b[2:]))    
   
ax.set(ylim=(0,10))
plt.tick_params(axis='x', colors='black', direction='out', length=13, width=6,labelsize=29)
plt.tick_params(axis='y', colors='black', direction='out', length=13, width=6, labelsize=29)
plt.show()
```

I have used different queries on here and other websites to get to this place.

I'd like to have custom error bars for X and Y and I'd like these error bars to be based on Standard error of the mean (SEM). I even calculated those by using SciPy, but I am having trouble putting them on the graph.
Is it possible to do so?